# S3 signed URL redirect on iphone download failed

Tags: ios, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular2-services

I've developed an Angular 2 application with a Node.js backend. I am using the aws-sdk to store files from the application. 
There is an function in the app where a user can download a pdf which has been uploaded to the app (and stored on s3). Essentially, the app requests a signedurl from s3 for the specific object, as in the code block below.

```
var params = {
            Bucket: projectid,
            Key: docName,
            VersionId: versionid,
            ResponseContentDisposition: 'attachment; filename ="' + docName+ '_' + versionid + '.pdf"'

        };
        var url = {
            link: s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)
        }
        res.status(200).send(url);
```

This url is returned to the front end and then angular opens the signed url in a new browser window, as in the line of code below.

```
        window.open(url.link.toString());
```

This works perfectly fine on desktops and android phones. 
When I try to open it on an iPhone, it opens a new tab, shows an icon of a file and then it says 'download failed'. The link in the browser however is correct and would work on any other device as mentioned.

I need to get this to work on all devices, could anyone possibly suggest a different way to download the file through the angular frontend which is iPhone friendly?

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? Have you tested your tab opening to google.com? PS the getSignedUrl() method doesn't interact with S3 in any way; it's a purely local computation.

Comment: @jarmod the link does work, I specifically copied the link from my iphone and emailed it to myself to try open it on my pc and it worked. Also, I didn't realise the getSignedUrl() function was a local computation, thank you :)

Comment: Can you try it with a small file that's simple to render, like a PNG file? Trying to understand if it's the request to S3 that's somehow messed up (maybe your phone provider added tracking query parameters or HTTP headers that cause the request to be rejected by S3 because the signature no longer matches). Also try it with a publically-readable object and instead of using the result from getSignedUrl, simply hard-code and use the public URL.